# Why isn't the YouTube iframe player calling onYouTubePlayerReady when it's loaded?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

I want to load a YouTube video, then mute, play, pause, and unmute it immediately. In doing this, I hope to present the user with a video that doesn't have a big play button on it, and does have the controls on the bottom. In order to do this, I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerid)
{
    mutePlayPauseUnmute(playerid);
}
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady(playerid)
{
    mutePlayPauseUnmute(playerid);
}
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady(playerid)
{
    mutePlayPauseUnmute(playerid)
}
function onPlayerReady(playerid)
{
    mutePlayPauseUnmute(playerid)
}

function mutePlayPauseUnmute(playerid)
{
    var player = document.getElementById(playerid);
    player.mute();
    player.playVideo();
    player.pauseVideo();
    player.unMute();
}
</script>
<iframe id="quotedVideo1" type="text/html" width="246" height="160" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/NWHfY_lvKIQ?modestbranding=1&rel=0&showinfo=0&autohide=1&iv_load_policy=3&theme=light&enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=quotedVideo1" frameborder="0"> <!-- Magic Comment --> </iframe>
```

However, upon inspection, neither `onYouTubePlayerReady`, `onYouTubePlayerAPIReady`, `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, `onPlayerReady`, nor `mutePlayPauseUnmute` is ever called. **What have I done wrong?** According to https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#onYouTubePlayerReady it looks like it should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: worth noting: "players must be at least 200px by 200px."

Comment: I know... the client requires it to be exactly this size :/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're confusing two different player APIs here.

Do you want to use the **iframe player**? If so, you'll want to look at: https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference.

Instead of defining `onYouTubePlayerReady`, you'll want to define the following method: `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady`, create your player, and then assign an `onPlayerReady` callback.

Make sure you're including the JavaScript for the iframe player API, in order for `onYouTubeIframeAPIReady` to be called:

```
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = o.protocol + "://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
```

---

Worth noting from the doc, since you're writing the iframe instead of using JavaScript to do that for you:

> If you do write the  tag, then when you construct the
>   YT.Player object, you do not need to specify values for the width and
>   height, which are specified as attributes of the  tag, or the
>   videoId and player parameters, which are are specified in the src URL.

Also, in your mutePlayPauseUnmute function..

```
playerid.mute();
playerid.playVideo();
playerid.pauseVideo();
playerid.unMute();
```

You'll want to trigger the actual the methods on the `player` as opposed to the `playerid` as described above.

Comment: Why did you quote that part of the doc about putting width and height in the tag? I did that...

Comment: you're still referencing the JS API when you're asking about the iframe player. they're different! even though you write your iframe tag, you actually have to import the JS and should subsequently create the YT.Player object.... look at the link above, search for "Loading a video player". **After the API's JavaScript code loads, the API will call the onYouTubeIframeAPIReady function**

Comment: also, i'm gonna throw this out there: a plugin i created to avoid all these issues -- https://github.com/nirvanatikku/jQuery-TubePlayer-Plugin

Comment: Thank you, but my higher-ups don't want any more plugins on the site XD
If plugins were okay, we'd use JWPlayer instead of YouTube :P

Comment: yeah that's totally fair, just passing along the reference so you can dig into the code if you wanna see how i'm doing things.. :)

Comment: I fixed it by just completely changing from the IFrame to the JS-embedded IFrame