# Youtube API fullscreen problems

Tags: javascript, api, youtube

I have an RSS newsreader project under development here: http://davidcool.com/feeds

I have this code that deals with embedding the youtube HTML player:

```
 /*!
 * Finds all youtube embeds and creates thumbnail + play button
 */

// Find all the YouTube video embedded on a page
var videos = document.getElementsByClassName("youtube"); 

for (var i=0; i<videos.length; i++) {

  var youtube = videos[i];

  // Based on the YouTube ID, we can easily find the thumbnail image
  var img = document.createElement("img");

  img.setAttribute("class", "item-thumb");
  img.setAttribute("src", "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/" + youtube.id + "/hqdefault.jpg");

  // Overlay the Play icon to make it look like a video player
  var playIcon = document.createElement("img");

  playIcon.setAttribute("class","item-play");
  playIcon.setAttribute("src", "play.png");   

  youtube.appendChild(img);
  youtube.appendChild(playIcon);

  // Attach an onclick event to the YouTube Thumbnail
  youtube.onclick = function() {

  // Create an iFrame with autoplay set to true
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
  iframe.setAttribute("id",this.id);
  iframe.setAttribute('allowfullscreen','1');
  iframe.setAttribute('frameborder','0')
  iframe.setAttribute("src", "http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + this.id + "?autoplay=1&autohide=1&border=0&vq=hd720&modestbranding=1&wmode=opaque&enablejsapi=1&origin=http://davidcool.com");

  // The height and width of the iFrame should be the same as parent
  iframe.style.width  = this.style.width;
  iframe.style.height = this.style.height;

  // Replace the YouTube thumbnail with YouTube HTML5 Player
  this.parentNode.replaceChild(iframe, this);

  if (iframe.requestFullscreen) {
    iframe.requestFullscreen();
  }
  else if (iframe.msRequestFullscreen) {
    iframe.msRequestFullscreen();
  }
  else if (iframe.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    iframe.mozRequestFullScreen();
  }
  else if (iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    iframe.webkitRequestFullScreen();
  }

  function onYouTubePlayerReady(iframe) {
    ytplayer = document.getElementById(this.id);
    ytplayer.addEventListener("onStateChange", "onytplayerStateChange");
  }

  function onytplayerStateChange(newState) {
    if ( newState == 0 ) {
     //cancel full-screen
     iframe.fullScreenCancel();
    }
  }

  }; // end onclick function  
} // end for statement
```

Things work properly for the most part. I have two issues:

1) The video loads and is able to go into full screen mode. But if you click the fullscreen button in the YouTube video player controls it stays in fullscreen and gets "stuck" there. If you don't click it and hit the "esc" key it will come out of full screen.
2) I added some code at the bottom to detect the state change and then automatically bring it out of full screen, but it seems to ignore this completely. I'm no javascript expert, perhaps someone knows of a way to fix these issues? I'm thinking these may be problems related to the API though? Any thoughts welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You have a function `onYouTubePlayerReady` that isn't called anywhere in the code you have posted.

I think you may be experiencing this problem:
[Why isn't the YouTube iframe player calling onYouTubePlayerReady when it's loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15003597/why-isnt-the-youtube-iframe-player-calling-onyoutubeplayerready-when-its-loade)

Also when I tried you page the video returns from fullscreen on a second click of the fullscreen icon. The video still takes up the whole page because you have set the iframe's size, is this really the behaviour you intended?